# "Called registerBroadcastReceiver twice" when checking Sim card state in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver that checks when Sim card state is changed using TelephonyManager.

```
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        TelephonyManager telephoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int simState = telephoneMgr.getSimState();
        String sim = Integer.toString(simState);

        switch (simState) {
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
                System.out.println("*******************************************Sim State absent******************************");
                Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State absent");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
                System.out.println("*******************************************SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED******************************"+simState);
                Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State network locked");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
                System.out.println("*******************************************SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED******************************"+simState);
                Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State pin required");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
                System.out.println("*******************************************SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED******************************"+simState);
                Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State puk required");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
                System.out.println("*******************************************SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN******************************"+simState);
                Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State unknown");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                    Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State ready");
                try{
                    String imsi = telephoneMgr.getSubscriberId();
                    Log.i("SubscriberId", "SubscriberId " + imsi);
                    if(imsi.equals("MY IMSI")){
                        Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim card is the same");

                    }
                    else{

                        Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim card is changed, Call the police");

                        // if phone is connected to the internet
                        if(isNetworkAvailable(context)){
                            Log.i("internet", "phone is connected");
                            Intent simChangedService = new Intent(context, SimChangedService.class);
                            SimChangedService.startYourService(context, simChangedService);
                        } // if phone is not connected to the internet, turns on 3G
                        else{
                            Log.i("internet", "phone is not connected");
                            setMobileDataEnabled(context, true);
                            Log.i("internet", "Mobile data enabled");
                            Intent simChangedService = new Intent(context, SimChangedService.class);
                            SimChangedService.startYourService(context, simChangedService);
                        }


                        }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("SubscriberId", "SubscriberId is null");
                    Log.i("SubscriberId", e.getMessage());
                }
                break;
        }
```

Here is the onHandleIntent in the Intent Service :

```
public class SimChangedService extends IntentService {
    public static void startYourService(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
    getLock(ctxt.getApplicationContext()).acquire();
    ctxt.startService(i);
}
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try{
        getPhoneLocation();

        ArrayList<String> locationList = new ArrayList<String>();
        locationList.add(longt);
        locationList.add(lat);

        //Executes an AsyncTask to send an email
        SendEmailTask sendTask = new SendEmailTask(this);
        sendTask.execute(locationList);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "i have executed sendTask", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "i have executed sendTask");
        scheduleAlarm();
    }finally{

        PowerManager.WakeLock lock = getLock(this.getApplicationContext());
        if (lock.isHeld()) {
            lock.release();
            Log.i("wakelock", "lock is released");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I do not call registerReceiver(), i only have this in the manifest :

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.trackyourandroid.SimStateListener"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Everything is working fine, but i'm getting an error in the LogCat : "Called registerBroadcastReceiver twice".
Does anyone know a solution for that?
Thank you.

Comment: how do you register this receiver?

Comment: Where do you call `registerReceiver()` ?

Comment: @Shereef I do not call registerReceiver(), please check the edited question

Comment: @The.Blue.Shrimp can you post the logcat ?

Comment: @Shereef Here is what i'm getting in the LogCat : 
E/fb4a(:<default>):LocalFbBroadcastManager(7196): Called registerBroadcastReceiver twice.

Comment: Are you sure `LocalFbBroadcastManager` is related to your application ?

Comment: @Shereef Yes i think so. When the broadcast receiver detects a change of sim card, i start the intent service(to send an email).In the intent service i schedule an alarm every 30 seconds. Each time the intent service is called i get this message in the LogCat.

Comment: Can you post the code regarding this ? the service and how you start it

Comment: Can you make a break point in `startYourService` and tell me how many time is it called if you toggle your sim (either insert or remove it) or you can alternatively `Log.i(TAG, "Service started");`

Comment: The reason I ask this is because I use broadcast receivers with WIFI to get notified when wifi connects/disconnects and on each time the wifi state changes onreceive gets called 3 times, so maybe that's the case

Comment: @Shereef 
startYourService is called twice, first time when sim card is changed, second time after 39 seconds (i don't understand why) : 
03-23 16:59:39.718: I/debug(20986): start your service
03-23 17:00:18.247: I/debug(20986): start your service .

Comment: I needed to illustrate some code so I added an answer, may not fix your initial problem but it's maybe worth trying.

Comment: Any update regarding this issue @The.Blue.Shrimp ?? You got Twice i got the message thrice :)  You can see one of my post here regarding this issue ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010805/broadcast-receiver-works-differently-on-different-version-of-android-4-1-1-4

Answer (score 3):

```
class Bla extends BroadcastReceiver {

static int mSimState = -1;


    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        int simState = telephoneMgr.getSimState();
        if(simState != mSimState) {
            mSimState = simState;
            //………the rest of your code………switch (simState) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first time the sim card is changed, `startYourService()` is only called once, but i still get “Called registerBroadcastReceiver twice” several times.
If the sim card is changed another time, then the Intent Service is never called since mSimState = simState, and i also get “Called registerBroadcastReceiver twice”. Thank you anyway for your answer!